# Adobe AIR NativeProcess fails with quotes in arguments?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

I try to launch a native process.
Arguments are separated by double quotes.
The commande line is : C:\OrthoProg\OrthoView\Viewer.exe “Office Dupont” “26000” “LB” “Laurence Durand” “222” “SABATIER” “Paulo” “F” “14/08/1997”

I try to do same with native process:

```
var file:File = new File(pathExe);
var nativeProcessStartupInfo:NativeProcessStartupInfo = new NativeProcessStartupInfo();

nativeProcessStartupInfo.executable = file;
var processArgs:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();

processArgs[0] = '"'+nomCabinet+'"';
processArgs[1] = '"'+cpCabinet+'"';
processArgs[2] = '"'+"OR"+'"';
processArgs[3] = '"'+prenNomPrat+'"';
processArgs[4] = '"'+idPatFR+'"';
processArgs[5] = '"'+nomPat+'"';
processArgs[6] = '"'+prenPat+'"';
processArgs[7] = '"'+sexPat.substr(0, 1)+'"';
processArgs[8] = '"'+naissPat+'"';
nativeProcessStartupInfo.arguments = processArgs;

var processMV:NativeProcess = new NativeProcess();
processMV.start(nativeProcessStartupInfo);
```

So, in my case application start but with any parameter!

Can you help me to solve that?

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

From the first look your method is correct and it should work,
i worked on project that sends arguments to exe and it works correctly,
now to debug this create a .Net windows application and view the received arguments using `MessageBox.Show` i think this will guide you to the problem.